# SQL "splitted" group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
('cat', 5000, 7000, 'A'),
('dog', 9200, 11000, 'A'),
('fog', 6500, 9300, 'B'),
('fox', 16001, 15001, 'B'),
('cat', 5005, 7005, 'B'),
('dog', 9299, 11399, 'B'),
('cat', 5005, 7005, 'B'),
('dog', 9299, 11399, 'B'),
('fox', 16001, 15002, 'A')
```

I need to obtain a selection groub by first column and then 4 columns with the sum of:

col2 for A flag,

col3 for A flag,

col2 for B flag and

col3 for B flag.

How can I get this?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca8da/2)

Comment: Please add expected query results.

Comment: @M.Massias The expected result is in the accepted answer now ^.^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Animal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flg = 'A' THEN V1 ELSE 0 END) AS A_V1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flg = 'A' THEN V2 ELSE 0 END) AS A_V2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flg = 'B' THEN V1 ELSE 0 END) AS B_V1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flg = 'B' THEN V2 ELSE 0 END) AS B_V2
FROM
    MyTab
GROUP BY
    Animal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select animal, 
    SUM(If(flg='A',V1,0)),
    SUM(If(flg='A',V2,0)),
    SUM(If(flg='B',V1,0)),
    SUM(If(flg='B',V2,0))
from MyTab
group by animal
```